# How to parse a specific value out of a csvfile uising csvhelper c#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

I am trying to parse a certain csvFile using csvHelper. The file constitutes as follows:

```
value: 333_345, nextval: 5578

val, 1val
200, 300
```

What makes this csv file unique is that the line (value: 333_345, nextval: 5578) are not headers and that the real headers do not start until the line (val, 1val)

I know that get to the headers (val, 1val) i can just call skip record function to jump all the way down there. My question is, how would I be able to get the values from the first line?

Specifically these ones(value: 333_345, nextval: 5578)

What ive tried so far is this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"path"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();//necessary for mapping 
                csv.Read();
                var records = csv.GetField(0);
            }
.
.
.

 public class Foo
    {
        [Index(0)]
        public string value { get; set; }


    }


    public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
    {
        public FooMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.value).Index(0);

        }
    }
```

With this, by setting the index to [0], i get the first line, but it gives it to me in a horizontal string:

```
v
a
l
u
e
:
3
3
3
_
3
4
5
```

what would I have to do for it to just return (333_345)?

Comment: Read with StreamReader while row is empty or line contains a colon.  Then start parsing the CSV data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use both attribute and class mapping. If you use attribute mapping, you don't need to register a class map.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("value: 333_345, nextval: 55578");
    s.AppendLine();
    s.AppendLine();
    s.AppendLine("val, 1val");
    s.AppendLine("200, 300");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();

        var val = csv.GetField(0);
        var nextval = csv.GetField(1);

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();

        records.Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

note: `Dump()` is a LINQPad extension that outputs the variable.